# Mongoose 4.11.0 Promises timing out

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I'm using mongoose and bluebird.
The setup is by-the-book, and is using the `useMongoClient` option, as requested by the notification.

```
Mongoose.connect(myConnectionString, {useMongoClient: true});
```

however none of the promises I use execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/starbucks', { useMongoClient: 
true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('openUri', function() {
// we're connected!
});
```

I have used this code for latest version and warning has gone. Please try it. Or use older version.

Comment: Worked like a charm mate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this is likely a bug with mongoose

problem went away after rolling back mongoose version

```
npm uninstall -save mongoose
npm install -save mongoose@4.10.8
```

**OR** you can remove the `useMongoClient` option `Mongoose.connect(connectionString);`,  and ignore the message

> DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md
shows

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

This code solves all deprecation warnings:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

Example:
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
module.exports.connect = uri => {
  mongoose.connect(uri, {
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    useMongoClient: true
  });
  // plug in the promise library:
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
    console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  // load models
  require("./user");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For further reading, a contributor discusses new behaviors here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399#issuecomment-312523545